# Como permitir que nightwatch tenga acceso a vídeo o audio

Tags: javascript, navegador-web

Estoy usando nightwatch hacer pruebas a mi aplicacion web.

En un punto durante que se utiliza la app requiero usar la cámara del ordenador, por lo que sale sale este mensaje en todos los navegadores:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Existe una forma de dar "permision" programaticamente con esta tecnologia?

Este mi codigo:

```
module.exports = {

  "Crear una nueva sesión" : function ( client ) {
    client
      .url( client.launch_url )
      .waitForElementVisible( "body", 1000 )
      .setValue( "input[type='password']", client.globals.password )
      .pause( 500 )
      .submitForm( "button[type='submit']" )
  },

  "Seleccionar idioma" : function ( client ) {
    client
      .click( "input[id='ingles']" )
      .submitForm( "button[type='submit']" )
  },

  "Buscar reversa con campo vacio" : function ( client ) {
    client
      .submitForm( "button[type='submit']" )
      .setValue( "input[type='text']", client.globals.reserva )
      .submitForm( "button[type='submit']" )
  },

  "Cerrar el modal de los comentario" : function ( client ) {
    client
      .click( "button.close" )
      .pause( 300 )
  },

  "Editar fecha de devolucion" : function ( client ) {
    client
      .click( "a.modalReservacionDevolucion" )
      .waitForElementVisible( "div#modalDevolucion" , 1000 )
      .click( "select#oficina_de_devolucion" )
      .click( "option[value='2']" )
      .pause( 500 )
      .click( "input#fecha_devolucion" )
      .waitForElementVisible( "div#modalDevolucion" , 1000 )
      .click( "div#ui-datepicker-div table tbody tr td.ui-datepicker-days-cell-over " )
      .pause( 1000 )
      .submitForm( "button[type='submit']" )
  },

  "Click en Documentos requeridos" : function ( client ) {
    client
      .waitForElementVisible( "body" , 1000 )
      .click( "button[type='submit']" )
  },

  "Conduce titular" : function ( client ) {
    client
      .waitForElementVisible( "body" , 1000 )
      .click( "button[type='submit']" )
  },

  "Tomar foto de la licencia del conductor" : function ( client ) {
    client
      .waitForElementVisible( "body" , 1000 )
      .click( "button[type='button']" )
      .acceptAlert()
      // .acceptSslCerts()
      // .waitForElementVisible( "camera-output-photo" , 1000 )
      // .click( "div#take-snapshot" )
      // .pause( 1000 )
  }

}
```

Comment: Lo dudo mucho. El acceso a la cámara es un problema de seguridad, por lo que el navegador no puede acceder a ella sin pedir permisos antes.

Comment: Ni loco, pretendes activar una cámara sin permiso del usuario??? Eso no tiene ningún sentido si lo que quieres hacer no es dudoso.

Comment: No puedes hacer eso, lo que sí puedes hacer es configurar el chrome que estés usando para hacer las pruebas para que no pida los permisos (pero si lo haces procura no usarlo para navegar, podrías instalar la versión Canary para estas cosas en paralelo al chrome normal)